# Product over permutations of powers

Tags: combinatorics, exponentiation, products

I have a product of the form:

$$
a_{1}^\alpha a_{2}^\beta a_{3}^\gamma ... a_{k}^\zeta
$$

where each of $$\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,...\zeta$$ can take values from 0 to n

$$
\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,...,\zeta \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, ... , n \}
$$

I'm using alpha, beta, .. because I have trouble with double subscripts otherwise I'd use \alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n+1}

and $$a_{1}, a_{2}, ...,a_{k} $$ are coprime.

With other words the product has a variable length of elements and the set S contains all products resulted of the factors with permutated powers...

Now my first question is, how can mathematicy represent the set S?

$$
S = \{a_{1}^0a_{2}^0a_{3}^0...a_{k}^1,a_{0}^0a_{2}^0a_{3}^0...a_{k}^1,...,a_{1}^1a_{2}^0a_{3}^0...a_{k}^0,...,a_{1}^na_{2}^na_{3}^n...a_{k}^n\}
$$

My second question is, how would I calculate the cardinality of this set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the set $S$ as

$$
S=\left\{\prod_{i=1}^ka_i^{\alpha_i}: \alpha_i\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}\right\}
$$

As far as the cardinality of $S$ is concerned, you have $n+1$ possibilities for each of the $k$ terms $a_1,\dots a_k$ (since $n+1$ is the cardinality of $\{0,1,\dots n\}$). Since $a_i,\dots a_k$ are coprime, no element can be counted twice.  Hence $$|S|=(n+1)^k.$$

Comment: It's not so simple.  Since the bases are not necessarily coprime, some choices of exponents can result in the same value.

Comment: I interpreted the question more as a request of counting all the elements of $S$ regardless of whether two elements can be equal or not. Your objection is perfectly right in your interpretation, but then it's impossible to answer without knowing anything about $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: I don't know about impossible without explicit values, but you are right that it does not look easy.

Comment: Of course it is possible to list a series of cases with different assumptions on $a,b,c,d$, but it would be an extremely long (possibly infinite) list different cases. Thanks for pointing it out anyway

Comment: Well, that would be the most obvious approach, but necessarily the only one.

Comment: Given a number of terms in the product a,b,c,d, .. let's rather call them 

$$a_{k}$$ 

for convenience. 

These elements are coprime indeed, I didn't specify that, thanks for pointing out. I would then have to represent the terms in S using product notation over unique permutations of alpha, beta, (this is mainly my difficulty) ... and the cardinality of |S| will be given by (n+1)^k if I understand this correctly. How could this be then represented?

Comment: @alle2004 If the elements are coprime, then you should edit the question.

Comment: @alle2004 good to hear that Qudit's remark was useful. I suggest you edit your question to include the fact that $a,b,c,d$ are indeed coprime. What do you mean by "how could this be represented"?

Comment: @alle2004  Sorry to be picky, but if $a,b,c,d$ are coprime, my answer is correct. Why did you un-accepted it?

Comment: @alle2004 I saw your edit to the question and re-answered the question. However, I suggest you edit the question again: it doesn't make sense to take $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ now since you have $k$ elements (not only 4)

Comment: @alle2004 You shouldn't edit a question if it substantially changes it.  It is better to ask a separate question.

Comment: @John, just to clarify, using your notation, will alpha take (potentially) different values for each factor or will it take the same value alpha_{i} for all factors in all products?

Comment: @alle2004 of course it can take different values. Each $\alpha_i$ can be different from the others.